# Need a simple shopping cart for Stripe

Tags: ecommerce

I have a Craft site I am building that will be selling about 20 templates with private password protected content (each a product basically). I need to allow people to "buy" access to each page. These purchases are one time and not a recurring subscription. Customers would have lifetime access to each product page content.

I have use plugins like Charge on other sites with Stripe. This works great for single product sites, but we want to allow people to buy access to more than one product. Is there any way to just build a simple cart with Craft to work with Stripe? Is there any cart code samples for Stripe? My needs are simple but I have been having a hard time finding an option without using a 3rd party solution like Foxy or Snipcart. Any ideas or suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like [Sprout Commerce](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/commerce) can handle your situation – multiple products, user-specific access, and Stripe.

At the time of this post, the product is still in private beta but if you'd like to drop us a note with more details (via the 'Request Preview' button on the site), we are happy to talk things through and see if your project would be a good fit.